# C# Class Property Getter Invoked Automatically

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

I have 2 class properties defined like so:

```
    private static string _validationError;
    public static string ValidationError
    {
        get {
            var temp = _validationError;
            _validationError = "abc";
            return temp;
        }

        set { _validationError = value; }
    }

    public static string CurrentError { get; set; }
```

A method:

```
    public static bool IsErrorStringEmpty()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dddd");

        return false;
    }
```

Test Method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidationErrorTest()
    {
        CurrentError = "My Error";

        var empty = IsErrorStringEmpty();
    }
```

When I debug this test, this is the behavior I'm seeing:

1. Before the 2nd line of the test method is hit, ValidationError = null (Expected).

   [image]
2. When it enters IsErrorStringEmpty(), before the 1st line is hit, ValidationError = null (Expected).

   [image]
3. Then, right when it's hitting the 1st line, ValidationError = "abc". I don't know how this getter is being invoked at all even though I have no explicit code up to this point to access the ValidationError property.

   [image]

I have breakpoint in the getter, but it didn't get hit, and the Call Stack is shown as below.

[image]
[image]

I'm sure it's somewhere but I can't seem to find it. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put a break point in your getter, and then look at the call stack when your code breaks.

Comment: You're invoking the getter in the debugger. Watch `_validationError` instead.

Comment: Oh my! Thank you :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're invoking the getter in the debugger. When code is executed in the evaluation of a property for display in a watch window it is really being executed, with real side effects.

Try watching `_validationError` instead.

Side effects in a getter can throw you for a loop. Best to avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

As with quantum effects, you change the outcome by observing it. Look at what you are debugging. You try to see what is inside of `ValidationError`, and thus you are invoking the getter.

You should add `_validationError` in your debugger instead of `ValidationError`.

The better question is why this property is not updated the second time your code pauses. You observed the property before and did not reset it anywhere, so this should have become `"abc"`.